# Elegant way for opening data files depending on their extension

Tags: python

In a folder that I supply to my script, files can have two extensions that require two different methods of opening the data files. I have used a `for` loop to `try` and open these files depending on there extension. An example code is supplied below:

```
for idx in range(len(xa)):
  filename = folder + xa[idx]
  try:
    data = numpy.load(filename + ".extention1")
  except:
    try:
      data = pyfits.loadtxt(filename + ".extention2")
    except:
      sys.exit("\nrun_" + str(xa[idx]) + " is a wrong file!\nScript terminated\n")
```

The code works perfectly. However, I am wondering if there is a more elegant/shorter way to do this?

Comment: What is `xa`? Does `filename` not *include* the extension? Have you considered a dictionary `{".ext": open_function}`?

Comment: why not iterate directly over `xa` `for idx in xa:`

Comment: `xa` can be seen as an array containing strings. This string can for example be: `exp_1`. Hence, `xa = numpy.array(['exp_1', exp_2', 'exp_3'])` would correspond to me trying to load the data files `exp_1`, `exp_2`, and `exp_3`. File extensions are not included.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap this in a function, and hold the different handling functions and extensions in a dictionary:

```
def load_file(filename):
    """Attempts to load the file and return the data."""

    HANDLERS = {'.ext1': numpy.load,
                '.ext2': pyfits.loadtxt}

    for ext, func in HANDLERS.items():
        try:
            return func(filename + ext)
        except:
            pass
    else:
        raise IOError("'{0}' could not be loaded.".format(filename))
```

Then your outer loop becomes:

```
for file in xa: # iterate over 'xa' directly, rather than by 'idx'
    try:
        data = load_file(folder+file)
    except IOError:
        sys.exit(...)
    ...
```

If you do need `idx`, use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for idx, file in enumerate(xa):
```